# Font Awesome fa-toggle-on is not displaying

Tags: font-awesome

I'm having trouble with the Font Awesome toggle on and off icons not appearing.  All of the icons that I have been using have been working, but now this one doesn't seem to.  Is there a work around, or a fix I can apply?  I'm simply doing:

```
<i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I updated my css reference to the latest font-awesome stylesheet and now is all working.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```